# How to generate truly random and secure session ID's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, cookies

I want to create session middleware for Express, but I don't know how to generate random and secure session ID's. How do big frameworks (such as Django and Flask) tackle this? How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

With session ID's, you want it to be psuedo random, so it cannot be guessed easily, but you also need to ensure that two users cannot receive the same ID. If you have some sort of per-user identifying information, such as username or IP address, I would use those, and then hash them. Here is an example:

```
const SHA2 = require("sha2");
sessionId = SHA2.sha224(username + ipAddress + secretKey)
```